# Foundation 4 Adaptive Lightbox using Reveal and Interchange

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, adaptive-design

Is there an option to use [Foundation 4 Reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) with images, but make them loaded only when the use click an element to open the modal?

My goal: create an Adaptive Lightbox with Interchange; When a user click a thumbnail, it will display an image in a full screen taking advantage of the [Interchange](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html) for adaptive images, so a smaller image will load for smaller screen and a larger image will load for a larger screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Reveal is to be used as a model box for specific interests such as a notification or a login box.

If you wish to use a "lightbox" style for say an image gallery then one would use [Clearing](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html).

Comment: I looked at it before, but I can't see how Cleaing can be used with Interchange if the anchor is linked to only on image. A code will be useful. Thanks

Comment: Apparently I did not understand your question to the fullest the first time I read it.

Your basically wanting to make a 'Full Screen' image preview of the thumb when clicked, depending on the device it will then adapt to the devices screen size? Correct?

Comment: Yes, but instead of the image resizing only, I want it to load a different image size, the same way Interchange works.